# Post a variable to json format in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I apologize if this question seems basic as I am new to both stackoverflow and javascript in general.

My goal here is to store the user's dropdown menu selection as well as some other user inputs into variables, then I want to post the json file that contains the variables into a specific route where my serve-side javascript can read from. I have the variable part and user selection part covered, however, I am having trouble posting the variables to the specified route.

So in my app.js file in my ember framework, I tried the below code to test out if I can post *{12345}* to *address:port/api/iwantmyjsonhere/* but when I run it and go to that specific page (*address:port/api/iwantmyjsonhere/*), it says cannot GET.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ url : "/api/iwantmyjsonhere/",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : "json",
        data: "12345"
    });
});
```

I understand that this question is lower level, so if you guys are too busy to answer, point me to any resources that might help me would be greatly appreciated too! Thanks in advance!

Comment: type: 'GET' ,data:{'data':12345} php: $_GET['data']

Comment: 1. Why there is the ember tag? It has nothing in common except for your framework.

Comment: 2. _it says cannot GET_ - what does that exactly means?

Comment: @DmitryTonkonogov I tagged ember because I thought the error might be cause by ember. I'm still new to the framework. And the webpage response was "Cannot GET /api/iwantmyjsonhere/", sorry if I wasn't clear earlier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is not related to ember anywhere.
You are just using jQuery for ajax call and as per jQuery standards "Data" Object must be Key/Value pairs.

Means you should do something like  -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ url : "/api/iwantmyjsonhere/",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : "json",
        data: {id:"12345"}
    });
});
```

You can read more on this one at -
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

And if you want to implement it in ember way the you can use something like -

```
return Ember.$.ajax({
            url: '/api',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {//key value pairs}
        }).then(function(result){
                //After ajax is successful.           
       }
```